# Obj-c - Disable uibutton if textView is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to disable my uibutton if a UITextView is empty with the below code. The button disables if the field is empty, however, when I use the below, the button doesn't seem to "enable" if the text view has values in it? Any idea why this is?

---

**Edit/Update**: I've updated my code below (problem half solved). In this scenario, my send button is disabled if the text view is empty. However, once I have text in my view and I press send, if I hit send a second time (and the text view is once again empty), send button is no longer disabled. Why is this?

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];

            self.sendButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

         }

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.sendButton.userInteractionEnabled = (textView.text.length > 0);

}
```

Comment: because you put the code in viewDidLoad which only executed once when the controller is loaded. You should check about UITextField delegate and learn how to use it.

Comment: @Surely Initially, I had it in textViewDidBeginEditing, but still no dice?

Comment: Why was my question down voted?

Comment: Your problem is half solved means the solution works. The reason why second time it is not working is because if you set the textview's text to empty manually, the delegate method will not be fired, you need to disable it manually as well. And probably you want to use "setEnabled" method instead of userInteractionEnabled.

Comment: @Surely You are a genius - totally correct. THANK YOU!! Any suggestion re: how I should be clearing the textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `UITextView` delegate:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    sendButton.userInteractionEnabled = (textView.text.length > 0);
}
```

Comment: Super odd - with this code in place, I can tap the button when there's no text in the textview, but it's disabled when there is text in the view? lol

Comment: Is this answer written in swift? Need it for obj-c.

Comment: No dice - button still allows me to tap it if textview is empty :/

Comment: Correction (kind of): When I first tap the textview, and it's empty, my button is disabled. When I put text in the view, the send button is now enabled. However, if I hit send again immediately after and my textfield is once again empty, it allows me to tap send - how do I disable the button again after initial text is cleared from the view?

Comment: If your textview is empty by default, you should set `sendButton.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE`; in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Still same problem. Everything seems to work as it should, until I go and hit the send button for the second time after my textview has cleared and is empty. The send button is again enabled (when it should be disabled).

Answer (score 0):

you must be setting text in self.replyField after viewDidLoad is executed.

try executing below code whenever you change the value in self.replyField:

```
    if (self.replyField.text.length > 0) {
        sendButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        sendButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
```

you can use isEnabled instead of userInteractionEnabled

Comment: Oddly enough, when I use this, the send button is disabled when text IS in the field...and enabled when it's not?

Comment: The button is enabled if there's no text in the field using the above.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement below delegate method for enabling and disabling button based on text values

```
optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
      replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
}
```